# Review ban for one single (opinable) incorrect review?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension

I just failed one [review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/8591888). I don't agree because post itself IMO din't need to be deleted (and edit was more appropriate): it had a link to user's website (self advertising, I guess). Anyway just after that I had this message:

> You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a task you
>   should have reviewed differently, see:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/8591888.
>
> Come back in 2 days to continue reviewing.

How can I *"...made too many incorrect reviews..."* if I failed just **one** review? If I remember well this threshold was (much) higher. In case, where can I see all my failed audits?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You weren't automatically banned due to having a sufficient number of failed audits; you were banned manually by a moderator.

Note that when he says, "incorrect reviews" he isn't just talking about audits.  He's asserting that you're inappropriately reviewing *real, actual posts*.

As for the specific audit that you failed.  It was pure spam.  Nothing about the answer was appropriate.  The post was by a spam account specifically created to advertise a product, and they posted an answer that looks, at a glance, to possibly be an actual answer, but whose actual contents is essentially just a bunch of meaningless and entirely irrelevant statements followed by an obfuscated link that has no content whatsoever related to the question.  Yes, this is sneaky, but *your job as a reviewer is to catch stuff like this*.  When you fail to mark spam as spam you're failing in your primary role as a reviewer.  You've been banned to give you time to reflect on this and to appreciate the importance of looking closely when reviewing.

Comment: Sorry, another question: if I reviewed incorrectly "real actual posts" then I would see them, is there a way to know which reviews were incorrect? Should I flag a random post to ask clarification or just wait he sees this question on meta?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Typically the mod would include examples in the ban message.  As it is, you can look through your own history, look for posts you approved and didn't act on that have since been deleted, closed, heavily downvoted, required serious editing, got comments indicating (non-technical) problems with the posts, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I won't see deleted posts but I guess there should be something!

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti If you try to view the post from a review that you approved, and can't see it, then you'll know it was deleted, and that you did something wrong.  If you end up seeing a lot of the posts you reviewed as being okay have been deleted, then you know you're doing something really wrong.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - Actually, you were not banned manually by a moderator. The post you approved: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30965579/19679 was spam. While the code looks fine, pay attention to the last sentence, which has a shortened link to a commercial website design company. Be very suspicious of posts like that by new users coming through review. Based on the 2-day ban, this probably was at least your second audit failure in the last week, but even moderators don't have good tools for searching or organizing reviews.

Comment: @brad oh, ok!!! Thank you very much!