# Review banned period doubled for one single failure on a Low-Quality review which seems not a spam

Tags: discussion, status-completed, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension

I've known that inside the Low-Quality queue, one could be banned due to a single audit failure if the review is "spam" related.

Refer:

- [Review ban for one single (opinable) incorrect review?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297852/review-ban-for-one-single-opinable-incorrect-review)
- [Incorrectly picked post for audit on low quality queue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297690/incorrectly-picked-post-for-audit-on-low-quality-queue)

---

But, what if the audit is tricky?

For example here is my case: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/26001172

The **spam pattern** post may have a **company/product link** at the end.

But in this case, it answered the question (itself is kind of off-topic as well), and the link redirects to a public package's document which **has the license of MIT**.

Maybe it's not on the answer, but is it really spam?

If it's spam, why the similar posts still exist under that question?

It looks tricky enough in my opinion.

Is it acceptable/normal to potentially ban a user from the review with a huge period only for one tricky audit?

Comment: Inline code formatting is not for emphasis. It is for code. None of the things you've formatted as code in your post are actually code.

Comment: In response to now-deleted comments: Yes, abuse of formatting is a common reason for me (and others) to downvote posts. If you want to emphasize something, use bold or italics. They are the formatting options designed for emphasis. Inline code formatting is for code.

Comment: I absolutely hate using spam as Low Quality Posts review audits. Recommend Deletion is the **wrong** button to use for spam posts, as that pushes them toward review deletion, which allows the author to undelete the post (which leaves no trace for non-moderators). I usually Skip those and flag them as spam separately, but I know some others who review them as Looks OK to push them away from review deletion and I disagree that they should be penalized.

Comment: related: [How is this a bad answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361512/839601)

Answer (score 5):

I could not find any other failed review audits by you in the last 30 days with my new tool (other than the one you linked), so this is probably a bug and I've lifted the review suspension.

> [image]

Comment: I think it is a rolling window, so it's in the last "X amount of seconds"